# Nginx http to https redirects to the first server_name

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

I have a these 2 server blocks in my `nginx/sites-enabled/application.conf`:

```
upstream myapplication {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.net
                app2.example.net
                app3.example.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.net
                app2.example.net
                app3.example.net;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example_net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/example_net.key;
    ssl_verify_client off;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;


    location /apply {
        rewrite ^/apply(.*) $scheme://$server_name/?$query_string? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapplication;
    }
}
```

and this is my `nginx/nginx.conf`:
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    disable_symlinks off;
    # server_tokens off;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Proxy redirect
    ##

    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwared-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that if I visit **http** app2.example.net I am redirected to **https** app1.example.net when it should redirect me to **https** app2.example.net, however if I go straight to **https** app2.example.net then that works fine.

What am I missing out in this config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$server_name` will always use the first in the block.

You need to use `$http_host` which will take the requests host.

Alternatively just make 3 blocks for each domain will do the trick.

Comment: You're right. Posted an edit to your answer. no need for the `thinks` :)

Answer (score 1):

Nginx will pick the first entry of the `server_name` variable. Try using `$http_host` instead and see if that helps.

`$http_host` will take the requests host from the HTTP request directly. Seeing as you're using virtual hosts, you'll only get requests to that server block that contain one of those names, so HTTP requests will always contain one of those 3 hosts.